# Function "lacks return statement" but has typeguards for all the paths

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces and types (all of which are open to change)

```
interface Base {
    type: string;
}

interface A extends Base {
    type: "A";
    field: string;
}

interface B extends Base {
    type: "B";
    query: string;
}

interface C extends Base {
    type: "C";
    equal: number;
}

type BaseExtensions = A | B | C;

interface BaseWrapper<R extends BaseExtensions> {
    idType: string;
    base: R;
}

interface And {
    type: "AND";
    rules: Array<BaseWrapper<any>>;
}

interface Or {
    type: "OR";
    rules: Array<BaseWrapper<any>>;
}

type Rule<R extends BaseExtensions> = BaseWrapper<R> | And | Or
```

What I would like to do is write the following function:

```
function doAThingBasedOnTheRuleType(rule: Rule<any>): Thing {
    if (isAnd(rule)) {
        return DoAndThing(rule);
    }
    if (isOr(rule)) {
        return DoOrThing(rule);
    }
    if (isA(rule.base)) {
        return DoAThing(rule);
    }
    if (isB(rule.base)) {
        return DoBThing(rule);
    }
    if (isC(rule.Base)) {
        return DoCThing(rule);
    }
    // error, [ts] Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

}
```

I would expect that Rule starts out as `And | Or | BaseWrapper<A> | BaseWrapper<B> | BaseWrapper<C>` which should get narrowed down one by one. However, I get the error `// error, [ts] Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.`

1- Why is TS not able to infer the types?
2- How do I fix it?

I'm on TS 2.5.2

Comment: Short answer: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12825

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TypeScript's rule about implicit returns is enforced *syntactically* -- without knowing the types involved, there needs to be a return statement at all reachable exit points of the function.

To figure out that a given function's implicit return isn't reachable using the type system would require multiple "passes", which the type system currently doesn't do (for performance/complexity reasons).

For example, consider this code:

```
function fn1() {
    const f = fn2();
    if (f === "alpha") {
        return "A";
    } else if (f === "beta") {
        return "B";
    }
}

function fn2() {
    const f = fn1();
    if (f === "A") {
        return "alpha";
    } else if (f === "B") {
        return "beta";
    }
    return "gamma";
}
```

What's the type of `fn1()` ? It could be `"A" | "B" | undefined` if `fn2()` returns a value other than `"alpha"` or `"beta"`, or it could be `"A" | "B"` if those are the only return values. Well, let's check `fn2()` -- what's its return type? *That* depends on the type of `fn1()` -- `fn2` returns `"alpha" | "beta"` if `fn1` returns only `"A" | "B"`, or returns `"alpha" | "beta" | "gamma"` if `undefined` is a possible return value.

So to figure out the reachability of `fn1`'s implicit return, you have to do multiple "rounds" of inference where you refine the type of one function based on the type of another, and then repeat, and *hopefully* you reach a fixed point and don't infinitely recurse. That's a *lot* more expensive than just doing a single pass with syntactic enforcement of implicit returns.

The easiest fix is to simply add a `throw`:

```
    } else if (...) {
       return ...;
    }
    throw new Error("Shouldn't be reachable");
}
```

Or if you're really into code coverage, rewrite the `if` condition to an assert in the final block:

```
   } else {
       Debug.assert(x.kind === "B");
       return "C";
   }
```

Comment: Ok that was my intuition of how to do it, but I want to understand WHY. Your example version isnt the same as my version.

In my version, we know ahead of time that the inputs are of the finite set of types A | B | ... (for simplicity), and each typeguard should filter that down. Once I've done if (isA(rule)) {... return } TS knows that rule is no longer of type A. Similarly, in type B, C etc. Once there are no types left then it must no longer be reachable. 

I guess there are complex cases I'm missing, and maybe it's not fully generalizable like in the case you mention.

Comment: You'll rarely find behavior in programming languages where only the simple case works. If the compiler can't make some behavior work in all (or nearly all) cases, then it's simply not done at all. Languages want to be very predictable and special-casing simple scenarios decreases predictability very quickly.

Comment: This makes a lot of code worse, forcing a default case. If I later add a new type to the union, I want the compiler to give me all places where I need to add code to handle the new type. Sometimes, its not possible to provide a sensible default. Its rarely possible to provide a default that will work with all new types.

Comment: Control flow analysis *should* be able to deal with this and figure out that if `else` was added, it will never actually run because there is no `else` case.

Comment: It'd be nice to gain this! It's very easy to see with the eyes in some cases, maybe these cases can be more easily detected, and otherwise fall back to reporting an error in more complicated cases?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to throw any errors, and `isC` is your last rule check-point, couldn't you remove the condition (thus always returning the CThing at the end)?

```
function doAThingBasedOnTheRuleType(rule: Rule<any>): Thing {
    if (isAnd(rule)) {
        return DoAndThing(rule);
    }
    if (isOr(rule)) {
        return DoOrThing(rule);
    }
    if (isA(rule.base)) {
        return DoAThing(rule);
    }
    if (isB(rule.base)) {
        return DoBThing(rule);
    }

    return DoCThing(rule);
}
```