# Exhaustive check not working properly in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Why TypeScript fails to understand that the if/else handles all the possible cases and wants one more clause with `else` to handle the impossible case?

[Run in Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQUoGcFIC4oByASwDtThT4AbYjAXygB90td8IjiwAnCGHgCAJg2ZtM2PIm4kIfPgHs+4jBgBmAV3IBjakvJQB5EQoD6uw0nLAAFDMKwuASiLktAWwBGC9tlINbGCoBy4AOkcUVDJKajpiF2wBYC0+IwBGDghaHGhA0KjIrihkGIVlVSTglLSjACZs3PygsNli2VKY-kFhCDEk2vSoAGYmIA)

```
type State = { state: 'initial' } | 
             { state: 'prepared' } | 
             { state: 'error' }

function f(state: State): number { // Error here
  if      (state.state == 'initial')  return 1
  else if (state.state == 'error')    return 2
  else if (state.state == 'prepared') return 3
}
```

Error:

```
Function lacks ending return statement and return type 
does not include 'undefined'.
```

Comment: I think this may be a similar discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433840/function-lacks-return-statement-but-has-typeguards-for-all-the-paths

Comment: @Nick yes, seems that's the case, thanks