# Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'. in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am studying TS. I'm trying to make simple calculator.
How can I make it this calculator without switch statement?
If the if statement is used, an error occurs in return type.

[image: Screenshot of code]

```js
type Command = 'add' | 'substract' | 'multiply' | 'divide' | 'remainder';
const calculate = function (command: Command, num1: number, num2: number): number {
  if (command === 'add') return num1 + num2;
  if (command === 'substract') return num1 - num2;
  if (command === 'multiply') return num1 * num2;
  if (command === 'divide') return num1 / num2;
  if (command === 'remainder') return num1 % num2;

// switch (command) {
//  case 'add':
//      return num1 + num2;
//  case 'substract':
//      return num1 - num2;
//  case 'multiply':
//      return num1 * num2;
//  case 'divide':
//      return num1 / num2;
//  case 'remainder':
//      return num1 % num2;
//  default:
//      throw Error('unknown command');
// }
};
console.log(calculate('add', 1, 3)); // 4
console.log(calculate('substract', 3, 1)); // 2
console.log(calculate('multiply', 4, 2)); // 8
console.log(calculate('divide', 4, 2)); // 2
console.log(calculate('remainder', 5, 2)); // 1
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMoF4oHJnrq5QA+eAzgK4BG5wATsgMbDFm4KUA2wAlmFxBs86XgDde6CMNz0IKXhgj1cAbgCwAKC1M4qOlCbIuTbsmDQcAM0qoWvPVAAUupGnQAuWIhQYANFColAgAjF5BCNTKAREATOHBUfQAlAmRylAA3lpQULxWzq6+mFileAREyVBywJT0qIHBIVAA1I0IsRqaufmFPu7YZbhUtAzMrFU1dQ0RzQC07Z05eQUu-RiDOBzcfAJCkxC19e3NAFSLXT2rRQOlW6ISUrgHRzNNUAD0F8u9a24bdzwcgUShUL2mJygAFJvtpNB8vuQAO68YBMAAWfX+6Cq2XhX0MyHI0HwhFwHi0CNy1Oqhwhs1asKphOJFBodEYLHJlIJNKmxwZCziXWZRlZ2x4-EE3PxNNy-LeoSg52FPNyYpJD0k0gpsrlCshX1Veo1QPkyEUUhUuuZfLpAveMONzKkVmQOxtvOpwHR9DgSKgAFF6H76E5cLYANaof0NG4YZ4ir4AXy0ya6un0cC4EAAdFw4ABzFzGUxccwQcMVXABEIBADMyWSqk+XwALDo9ORs3mC8WjCYzBZwyMOeMa1B67Wmy2qbFO1mc-miyXB+XhxLdtKAm2ArEZ62oAAOBfdpd91dlivhrVPHd7g9z0895f90tDyuyc2W5QTgCsD7NoeIRAA)

Comment: Have you tried a refactoring called "Replace Conditional with Polymorphism" ?

Comment: Technically this question is a duplicate of this: [Function "lacks return statement" but has typeguards for all the paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433840/function-lacks-return-statement-but-has-typeguards-for-all-the-paths). The context provided in the accepted answer is extremely useful but I'm thinking other solutions are more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript has a type checking paradigm as `type inference` and here it tries to find out what should happen for the return type if all your conditions won't match . You need to handle all return types, one of these solutions could be the bellow one:

```js
type Command = 'add' | 'substract' | 'multiply' | 'divide' | 'remainder';
const calculate = function (command: Command, num1: number, num2: number): number | void {
  if (command === 'add') return num1 + num2;
  if (command === 'substract') return num1 - num2;
  if (command === 'multiply') return num1 * num2;
  if (command === 'divide') return num1 / num2;
  if (command === 'remainder') return num1 % num2;

// switch (command) {
//  case 'add':
//      return num1 + num2;
//  case 'substract':
//      return num1 - num2;
//  case 'multiply':
//      return num1 * num2;
//  case 'divide':
//      return num1 / num2;
//  case 'remainder':
//      return num1 % num2;
//  default:
//      throw Error('unknown command');
// }
};
console.log(calculate('add', 1, 3)); // 4
console.log(calculate('substract', 3, 1)); // 2
console.log(calculate('multiply', 4, 2)); // 8
console.log(calculate('divide', 4, 2)); // 2
console.log(calculate('remainder', 5, 2)); // 1
console.log(calculate("badcommand", 2, 4)) // this won't return any value just error or undefined
```

If you are trying to change the function implementation due to the error you can make all the calculation functions like:

```js
type Calculation = (num1: number, num2: number) => number

const add: Calculation = (num1, num2) => {
    return num1 + num2;
}

const substract: Calculation = (num1, num2) => {
    return num1 - num2;
}
// Others
```

Comment: So for other solutions, you have to change or decouple your function

Comment: `number | undefined` won't work, it errors with "not all code paths return a value", see [this TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3aZ3w).

Comment: edited the post, if you won't need to return anything just use `void`

Comment:  `void` is what I would go with too. It matches the description given in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void): "the absence of having any type at all".

Comment: @Wing, please before writing any type of annotations define your considerations, `typescript` is designed for catching bugs on your development time and as we know it is a compile-time superset of javascript. so here you won't call `calcuate("badcommand", 2, 2)` on your own calls. if you want to remove unexpected commands from your program input so you should handle the exceptions.

Comment: I think you replied to the wrong person :)

Comment: @Wing, sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the `if`/`else` chain with a `switch` statement, then Typescript will correctly determine that the end of the function is unreachable, and therefore doesn't need a `return` statement; on the contrary, if you try to put a `return` statement at the end, you will get an error for "unreachable code".

Note that there is no need for a `default` clause here, though you could add one if you want more safety at runtime.

```
const calculate = function (command: Command, num1: number, num2: number): number {
  switch(command) {
    case 'add':
      return num1 + num2;
    case 'substract':
      return num1 - num2;
    case 'multiply':
      return num1 * num2;
    case 'divide':
      return num1 / num2;
    case 'remainder':
      return num1 % num2;
  }
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMoF4oHJnrq5QA+eAzgK4BG5wATsgMbDFm4KUA2wAlmFxBs86XgDde6CMNz0IKXhgj1cAbgCwAKC1M4qOlCbIuTbsmDQcAM0qoWvPVAAUupGnQAuWIhQYANFColAgAjF5BCNTKAREATOHBUfQAlAmRylAA3lpQUOQA7rzATAAWLj7uyVk5uYbI5ND4hLgeNbVQcsCU9KiBwSFQANR9CLEamu1GDRQ0dIwsLW21nd29EQMAtCNjS1ONnDz8gosT7R0QXT0jAwBU2+OT9Y2iElInZ+eXa-1QAPT3uyeeDkCiUKlap3aKyu6ygAFIAacAL5aJHjHR6chwLgQAB0XDgAHMXMZTFxzBAnE0iAEQgEAMzJZKqP7-AAsGP02LxBOJRhMZgsVKotAYzFYDNpTJZv3+sU5WJx+KJJIF5KFHG4fAEQgCbICsWlrKgAA4FdzlXzSYLKbgXpJpHqDUbZVB5ZpdFylbzVWSKVSQchFFIVAEAKzO5nGkJaIA)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to solve it:

```js
type Command = 'add' | 'substract' | 'multiply' | 'divide' | 'remainder';

const calculate = function (command: Command, num1: number, num2: number): number {
  return {
    'add':       () => num1 + num2,
    'substract': () => num1 - num2,
    'multiply':  () => num1 * num2,
    'divide':    () => num1 / num2,
    'remainder': () => num1 % num2,
  }[command]();
};

console.log(calculate('add', 1, 3)); // 4
console.log(calculate('substract', 3, 1)); // 2
console.log(calculate('multiply', 4, 2)); // 8
console.log(calculate('divide', 4, 2)); // 2
console.log(calculate('remainder', 5, 2)); // 1
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMoF4oHJnrq5QA+eAzgK4BG5wATsgMbDFm4KUA2wAlmFxBs86XgDde6CMNz0IKXhgj1cAbgBQ6pnFR0oTZFybdkwaDgBmlVC146oACm1I06AFyxEKDABooqSgQARg8AhGplPzCAJlDAiPoASjjw5SgAb3UoKDlgSnpUDKzsvAIiDxKSh0TsAD5-QKCoAGoGhGifYuzcKloGZlYParq2poBaNo6uvE4efkFcCuGserCmgCpJzsrcUQkpRcrl1caoAHot6dl5ZEUpFSGaldGoAFJL7IBfAG1nb3QALrVDSfDRaHTkOBcCAAOi4cAA5k5DMYuKYIA58IRcH4gn4AMyJRKqc4XAAs4N0UNh8KRBiMJjMmN6dEYLBxUHxuKJJLOF2ilMh0LhiORDLRTI43D4AiEfjJfmiPNJUAAHILqSK6SjGRjduJJNJ5YrlXyoALtFThbSxaj0Zi5AolCo-ABWE3ElVBIA)

Comment: You are trying to skip `typescript` checks, this is basically an antipattern.
What about the error if we pass `somebadcommand` on runtime?

Comment: @Heartbit. No, I'm *not* trying to skip Typescript checks. I'm using Typescript type checks. If you are going to pass an arbitrary string, there's hardly any meaning to define `Command`.

Comment: If the prop(function) not exists then you will get an error. so typescript's type inference feature can't find this bug

Comment: @Heartbit. You have to skip Typescript's type check to make that pass. If you add `console.log(calculate('foo', 3, 3));` then you will get a type error.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.
Using object instead of If statement and Switch statement not occurs compile error.

```js
type Command = 'add' | 'substract' | 'multiply' | 'divide' | 'remainder';
const calculate = function (command: Command, num1: number, num2: number): number {
    const test = {
        add: num1 + num2,
        substract: num1 - num2,
        multiply: num1 * num2,
        divide: num1 / num2,
        remainder: num1 % num2,
    };
    return test[command];
};
console.log(calculate('add', 1, 3)); // 4
console.log(calculate('substract', 1, 1)); // 2
console.log(calculate('multiply', 4, 2)); // 8
console.log(calculate('divide', 4, 2)); // 2
console.log(calculate('remainder', 5, 2)); // 1
```

Comment: No!!!! This is dangerous. All those expressions are being evaluated. If you want to go that route use @md2perpe solution - take note that the record (which you are calling object) is composed of functions as the values for a given string key, not expressions. You can specify the type for it like so: `type Test = Record<string, () => number>`

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) is cool but I wouldn't advise you bet too much on it.

Instead you can use a refactoring technique called ["Replace Conditional with Polymorphism"](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) to get rid of the `if` statements. Like so:

```
class Command {
    #num1 = 0;
    #num2 = 0;

    constructor(num1: number, num2: number) {
        this.#num1 = num1; 
        this.#num2 = num2;
    }
    get num1() { return this.#num1; }
    get num2() { return this.#num2; }
    command() {}
}

class AddCmd extends Command { 
    command() {
        return this.num1 + this.num2;
    }
}

class SubtractCmd extends Command { 
    command() {
        return this.num1 - this.num2;
    }
}

class MultiplyCmd extends Command { 
    command() {
        return this.num1 * this.num2;
    }
}

class DivideCmd extends Command { 
    command() {
        return this.num1 / this.num2;
    }
}

class RemainderCmd extends Command { 
    command() {
        return this.num1 % this.num2;
    }
}

console.log(new AddCmd(1, 3).command()); // 4
console.log(new SubtractCmd(3, 1).command()); // 2
console.log(new MultiplyCmd(4, 2).command()); // 8
console.log(new DivideCmd(4, 2).command()); // 2
console.log(new RemainderCmd(5, 2).command()); // 1
```

Think about how you can introduce typescript types to the above code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you would choose this technique? It doesn't seem like a refactor at all because you've broken the original interfaces defined in the OP and made the code much more complex.

Comment: Applying refactoring techniques popularized by Martin Fowler in Java is something you should seriously think twice about. Idiomatic code is radically different between the languages and there's a simple way to solve the problem

Comment: @AluanHaddad the refactoring techniques apply to any programming language. Also, using typescript narrowing is not idiomatic, it's relying on the typescript compiler to find for you missing paths. I would think a class-based approach is more likely to scale better in case you are to introduce more functionalities like `power`, `sin` etc

Comment: Yes, refactoring techniques may apply to any language but the question before any refactor is "does it improve the code?". I would argue it hasn't been improved here. A simple interface has been replaced with an extremely clunky one – a function call vs instantiating an object then calling a method. The new implementation itself is also much more complex – a single function with simple conditionals vs six classes. All of this means your code isn't easy to use and understand. In regards to scaling, given the simplicity of this function, additional conditionals are not a problem.

Comment: @Gilbert not all class systems are alike. Classes in JavaScript are always extensible, are first class values, are not types, inherent via a prototype chain, and both operands of instanceof are values and neither are types. Trying to transliterate patterns straight out of one language in another is a bad idea in general and these languages are diametrically opposed.

Comment: @Wing and Aluan , you were right. On reviewing this code 10 monhs later, its very apparent that its more complex than simple conditionals. There seems to be a 'javascript way' of writing code that even upto now I am not familiar with.